# Copy column and insert new value along with it

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 tables with the following fields.

```
Person: IDNumber, Name
Summary: IDNumber, Sports
```

I would like to copy Person.IDNumber to Summary Table and at the same time set Sports to Running assuming all the people's favourite sport is Running, doing the copying of column and setting the value to Running at the same time.
I am able to copy the whole column of Person.IDNumber to Summary.IDNumber, but how do i go about setting the value to Running for Summary.Sports?

```
Insert into Summary(IDNumber)
select IDNumber from Person
```

How should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a field expression to give you the value *"Running"* for every row of your `Person` table.

```sql
SELECT IDNumber, 'Running' AS Sports FROM Person
```

Then you can insert that result set into your `Summary` table.

```sql
INSERT INTO Summary(IDNumber, Sports)
SELECT IDNumber, 'Running' AS Sports FROM Person
```

Comment: Thanks HansUp for the quick response. Have tried it out and it works, thanks!